# Multiple Custom Point Annotations - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkannotationview

I am trying to give my two MKPointAnnotation pins a custom image. So far I am being able to display the same image on both pins. What could I do to the code below to give each pin a custom image?

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

        guard !(annotation is MKUserLocation) else {
            return nil
        }


        let annotationIdentifier = "AnnotationIdentifier"

        var annotationView: MKAnnotationView?

        if let dequeuedAnnotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: annotationIdentifier) {
            annotationView = dequeuedAnnotationView
            annotationView?.annotation = annotation
        }
        else {
            annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: annotationIdentifier)
            annotationView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
        }


        if let annotationView = annotationView {
            annotationView.canShowCallout = true
            annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "Moto_pin")
        }

        return annotationView
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "Moto_pin")`, you will want to change the image for each pin. That line will assign the same image to each annotation view.

Comment: But how do I access the examplePoint = MKPointAnnotation() image?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use MKPinAnnotationView instead of MKAnnotationView. To do so you just need to change:

var annotationView: MKPinAnnotationView?

With this class you can customize your pin color and the whole view

Comment: I am trying to use an image not color the pin.